# Group by similar string field

Tags: sql, sybase

A table logs all files that have been generated for every report type in my application. I would like to determine the last time each report was generated.
All files are named NUMBERS_REPORTNAME-DAY-TIME.xml.

I would like to make a query that groups file names according to what's between the first sequence of numbers and the time stamps, what a regex would do.

Is this possible with SQL / Sybase?

```
FileName                                       GenerationDate

456879_REPORT-ONE-20150409-164652.xml           2015/04/09        
789456_REPORT-TWO-20150409-131534.xml           2015/04/09         
123458_REPORT-TWO-20150510-121055.xml           2015/04/10          
784111_REPORT-THREE-20150510-100652.xml         2015/04/10
```

to

```
FileName             GenerationDate

REPORT-ONE           2015/04/09                 
REPORT-TWO           2015/04/10          
REPORT-THREE         2015/04/10
```

Comment: Yes it is. You need to get substring ;)  `SELECT SUBSTRING(FileName, 8, 10) AS RepName, MAX(GenerationDate) AS GenerationDate FROM TableName GROUP BY SUBSTRING(FileName, 8, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(FileName, 8, 10) ReportName, MAX(GenerationDate) GenerationDate
FROM TableName
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(FileName, 8, 10)
```

Documentation:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01612.0500/doc/html/emc1297115087844.html
http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1260/html/iqref/Substr.htm
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1520/html/iqrefbb/Max.htm
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug118.htm

Comment: I think the AS is a typo. This doesn't suit my case, as the report name will not correctly be extracted (its size varies greatly).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( FileName , '((REPORT-)([a-zA-Z]*))' ) AS ReportName , 
       GenerationDate FROM x GROUP BY ReportName;
```

This should work regardless of how long the ReportName will get. // Only in Sybase

Comment: This looks good to me, but i get a `Function 'REGEXP_SUBSTR' not found`. Still investigating why

Comment: The function should be there I took it from the sybase doc. Maybe it's been only recently implemented

Comment: We've just migrated to Sybase 15. This function seems to be part of SQL Anywhere 12.0.1. Not sure if this installed by default, and our dev team does not manage the DB.

Comment: Yeah it seems to be part of sql anywhere